# Hide resize & selection column in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Is there a way to hide resize & selection column when I add some data in `DataGrid`'s `ItemSource`?

[image: A DataGrid without row selectors and a DataGrid with row selectors on the left.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the row selector column and it can be hidden using the [`HeadersVisibility`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.headersvisibility?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) property.

```
<DataGrid ... HeadersVisibility="Column">
```

A value of `Column` show all column headers but hides the row selectors, see possible values [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagridheadersvisibility?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#fields).